# Are these line height calculations legible and pleasing?

Tags: typography, css, line-height

I experimented a bit with calculating `line-height` of text with respect to `rem` and `em` units. What I came up with is this calculation:

```
line-height: calc((1rem * 6 / 10) + (1em * 8 / 10));
```

I've made a little demonstration with texts having `font-size`s ranging from `0.8rem` through `2.5rem` and you can select `html` `font-size` in a range from 12 to 28 for yourself with the range input at the top.

Also I limited the maximum with of every element to

```
max-width: calc(55 * 1em);
```

My question: Do you think, those values work?
For this the calculation leeds to smaller relative line-heights when the font-size is big. The results should be legible and pleasing, while taking up as less vertical space as possible.

The interactive example is seen here: https://s.codepen.io/HerrSerker/debug/e29b642ef84c06b02bdf00c6aa27861c

#### Edit:

I added a font-chooser in the example. I want this to work on a wide variety of fonts.

#### Note:

I know, that the smallest text is not very ledigle, if smallest `rem` of `12px` is chosen. But that is due to the fact of the small `font-size` (`9.6px` in that case) rather than the `line-height`. So please don't mock on the `font-size`s themselves.

Comment: Why not just use a line-height of 1.4 (without a unit)?

Comment: @AAGD I think of 1.4 being too big for big font sizes. I not only want legible text, but also pleasing one.

Comment: At least, who ever it was, when you downvote as first person, please give a comment on the reason.

Comment: @yunzen I think visually most fonts, font sizes and line-heights look great. I'm curious, where do you envision using this method? Although, I do some coding (very little) I find it super interesting.

Comment: Decisions like these always need to be made in context. As is, I think your question is primarily opinion based because of the ambiguity of it.

Comment: @ZachSaucier I'm aware about the opinion-based aspects of my OP. I want to lay emphasis on the legibility part.

Comment: The individual font-size / line-height pairings are ok, IMO could use a bit extra space. The width-limits and the overall page layout look like mess, though. Not clear what you're after...